# Deleting metrics from Prometheus produces error: not implemented

Tags: prometheus

I would like to delete all metrics for a time series `mymetricname{foo="bar"}` in a Prometheus 2.0.0-beta.2 installation.

I currently get an error message from this call to the [HTTP API](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/api/):

```
curl -X DELETE -g \
  'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/series?match[]=mymetricname{foo="bar"}'

{"status":"error","errorType":"internal","error":"not implemented"}
```

But then a [statement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prometheus-developers/lN8SxTsiaWU) from the [author](https://juliusv.com/) apparently suggests that this type of call became possible a long time ago (back in 2015). What is going on here?

**UPDATE** It seems unlikely that the problem is due to ill-escaped letters in the URL, because the following works just fine:

```
curl -X GET -g \
  'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/series?match[]=mymetricname{foo="bar"}'

{"status":"success","data":[<data>]}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Prometheus 2.0 the endpoint has moved to a POST with a body on `/api/v2/admin/tsdb/delete_series`

For example:

```
curl -XPOST -g 'http://localhost:9090/api/v2/admin/tsdb/delete_series' -d '{"matchers": [{"name": "__name__", "value": "up"}]}'
```

Comment: Thx, this is getting close. I've enabled admin control actions with `-web.enable-admin-api` and tried to map my actual time series into this parameter: `-d '{"matchers": [{"__name__": "mymetricname", "foo": "bar"}]}'`. However, curl returns `{}` and the time series so far seems unaffected

Comment: You can also use `min_time` and `max_time` properties to limit the amount of data deleted from the metrics.

Answer (score -1):

Investigating the [source code](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/v2.0.0-beta.1/web/api/v1/api.go#L359-L363) for Prometheus 2.0.0-beta.2 (`api.go` at line 361) indicates that this functionality is indeed not implemented. (This also applies for the current master branch.)

Issue [#2760](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2760) mentions that deletes are currently disabled in Prometheus 2.0.